# Why is my client not receiving any bytes?

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I am writing a simple client-server program. My server works fine with telnet, but my client can only send bytes, not receive them. Is there something obvious I'm missing? I think it may be because of my usage of the `recv` function in some way but it's not evident to me. The `recv` function consistently gets 0 bytes. I should add that the recv function doesn't block, yet the received number of bytes is always zero.

A snippet of the code in the client's main function is below. The function `changeIPOrPort` sets the servers ip address and port and works fine since the server receives the clients message.  I can post the server code as well if necessary.

```
int main() {

int client_fd, numbytes = 0;
//int quit = 0;
struct sockaddr_in their_addr;
char response[MAXDATASIZE] = "";
char buf[MAXDATASIZE] = "";
size_t len = 0;

/* Server config*/
their_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
memset(their_addr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof their_addr.sin_zero);
printf("Configuring the server\n");
changeIPOrPort(&their_addr);


printf("Hello! please input letters to know things about me.\n");
printf("Each character will give you a piece of information about me\n");
printf("%s\n", serviceInfo); //info string "UI"...

/*create client socket*/
client_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if(connect(client_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, sizeof(their_addr)) < 0) {
    printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
    return 1;
}

if(!fgets(response, sizeof (response), stdin)) {
    printf("Error reading line.\n");
}
else {
    len = strlen(response);
    if(response[len - 1] == '\n') {
        response[len - 1] = '\0';
    }
    printf("You entered the characters:%s\n", response);
    printf("sending...\n");
    send(client_fd, response, len, 0);

    numbytes = recv(client_fd, buf, strlen(buf), 0) ;
    if(numbytes < 0) {
        printf("Error receiving from server, quitting\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        printf("Number of bytes received: %d\n", numbytes);
        buf[numbytes] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", buf);
        printf("This is errno\n", errno);
    }
}
close(client_fd);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the actual symptomps of error?

Comment: The `recv` function doesn't block, yet `numbytes = 0` always.

Comment: I wonder what 'strlen(buf)' returns when buf is initialized with 'char buf[MAXDATASIZE] = "";'  ?

Comment: My god do I feel stupid. I have other issues but that solved my problem.

Comment: If you ever feel the urge to use strlen() in network code, look at the issue again, and again, 20 times over, and even then decide to not use it:)

Comment: @FSB in your code why you are creating socket two times..

Comment: @Shiv oh yeah!   Prolly. copy/paste disaster from some crappy website.  Many TCP server/client examples on the net are just apallingly sucky:(

Comment: @Shiv On a comical side, hedonism. On a realistic side, that was a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace 'strlen(buf)' with 'sizeof(buf)-1'